# Can't pass image from tableViewCell to viewController

Tags: segue

I try to get the jobImage shown on the DetailViewController when I press on the Cell, but the imageView on the DetailVC is empty...

Comment: please check out my recent answer and feedback

Comment: Could you place the following code in your JobDetailViewController's viewDidLoad and tell the result? Does the app crash?
`assert(jobDetails!.jobImage != nil)`

Comment: @ajeferson yes it crashes with following error "Thread 1: Assertion failed:"

Comment: @GifHunter111 Check if the code your `prepare(for:sender:)` executes correctly. Maybe your destination view controller can not be casted to `JobDetailViewController ` (maybe due to the controller being wrapped in a navigation controller, for instance).

Comment: @GifHunter111 another reason might be your `jobs[indexPath.row]` not having an image at all. You might wanna check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method `didSelectRowAt` that is in `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let job = jobs[indexPath.row] // get the Object
    let image = job.jobImage // get the Image
    let destinationVC = DetailVC()
    destinationVC.jobDetails = JobDetailViewController.JobDetails(jobDetail: jobs[indexPath.row].text, userName: jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser!, jobImage: jobs[indexPath.row].jobImage)
    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetails", sender: self)
}
```

Read more about `UITableViewDelegate` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate).

Comment: ah you need to pass the Image to the new view ?

Comment: yes, like the userName gets passed on the DetailVC but the jobImageView on the DetailVC stays empty where normally the jobImage should be, you know what I mean

Comment: Check out the New Edit

Comment: place a variable that hold the uiimage inside the detailsVC and use the code above and then inside the ViewDidload set the image to the imageView

Comment: it's still empty.. also didn't made any difference

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure few things,

- In `JobDetailViewController` the struct has the image in `jobImage` variable
- The `IBOutlet` `jobImageView` is connected in UI

Comment: Can you please print `jobDetails!.jobImage` in `JobDetailViewController` class?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean? I already got it in the code above

Comment: I want to see `print(jobDetails!.jobImage)`

Comment: oh ok i see, so the output doesn't print anything, I only get a warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIImage?' to 'Any'"

Comment: doing that what does it print?

Comment: it prints nothing